# Node js вызывает ошибку при работе async/await

Tags: node.js, express

```js
async function login(req, res) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (email === 'admin@gmail.com' && password === 'admin') {
      res.cookie('role', 'admin');
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      const result = await Users.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
          email,
          password,
        },
      });

      if (result.count > 0) {
        res.cookie('role', 'user');
        res.redirect('/');
      }

      res.render('login', { err: 'Error' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in login func', error);
  }
}
```

Ошибка: 
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Вызывается при отправке формы

```js
router.post('/', login);
```

Comment: Как вызывается эта функция? На первый взгляд, сам по себе этот код вызывать такую ошибку не должен.

Comment: О боже, я забыл добавить строку из-за которой ошибка) 
if (result.count > 0) {
        res.cookie('role', 'user');
        res.redirect('/'); // Вот из-за этой строки
      }

Comment: Покажите, как используется функция `login` (и, по возможности, не в комментариях, а отредактировав вопрос). Есть сильное подозрение, что проблема где-то там, к примеру, она может вызываться без `await`.

Comment: @Yaant поправил

Comment: Хм, любопытно. С ходу не готов сказать, что не так, а пытаться воспроизвести сейчас некогда. :(

Comment: После res.redirect неплохо бы return вставить. А то у вас страница ошибки пытается рендерится

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ответы - в ответы! :) Блин, очевидно же, а я смотрел, смотрел, и в упор не увидел. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить `return` после `res.redirect('/')` иначе у вас пытается отрендериться страница `res.render('login', { err: 'Error' });`

```
  if (result.count > 0) {
    res.cookie('role', 'user');
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
  }
```